# Color code issue in grid view rows while sort by click the header in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview, datagrid

In grid view by click the button in the form i have load the details from SQL table and based on some column condition colored the rows. When i load grid view the colors are applied perfectly but when i sort the grid view by click the column header the data gets sorted but the colors does not applied correctly based on the condition.

```
 Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sQuery, connection)
            command.CommandTimeout = 0
            Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            oModel.Rows.Clear()
            If sqlReader.HasRows Then
                oModel.Load(sqlReader)
            End If
            sqlReader.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            DataGridView1.DataSource = oModel
            Color_Grid()
            sqlReader.Close()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try


Private Sub Color_Grid()
        For i = 0 To oModel.Rows.Count - 1
            If oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("Days") <= 15 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
            ElseIf oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("Days") >= 16 And oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("Days") <= 21 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            ElseIf oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("Days") > 22 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato
                If oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("InStock") = 0 Then
                    If oModel.Rows.Item(i).Item("Committed") > 0 Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

[image]

After Sort:

[image]

Comment: Are you calling Color_Grid method after you sort the grid? Can you share the code of how are you sorting the grid? And this is not C# code so please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Just i have enabled the SortMode to automatic in the column property. I called the Color_grid method in DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is coming from the fact that you are looping thru the “DataSource” rows instead of the `DataGridView` rows. I may be mistaken about this, however, my understanding is that the “data source” may stay static and not necessarily be sorted when the user clicks on a column header to sort the grid. The “GRID’s” rows are sorted… but I am betting that the data sources rows are not reflecting this sort. This explains why the colors never change after the sort because the data source has not changed.

Below are changes to the posted code to loop through the grid instead of the data source when setting the colors. This works fine however, this does bring up a question of what if one of the “Days” values in the grid changes? Example, if the user is allowed to add new rows or change the “Days” values, or the value is changed through some other mechanism, then the posted code will loop through all the rows when a single row value was changed. To help, you could wire up the cell value changed event for the grid and check if the “Days” cell value changed. This will help avoid looping through all the rows when a single value changes.

Lastly, As @AugustoQ’s answer suggest, putting the `Color_Grid` method into the grids `Sorted` event will work as expected as long as you loop through the grid. That will set the row colors correctly, in addition the cell value changed event is added for cases when the “Days” cell value is changed. Below is an example of what is described above. Hope this helps.

```
Private GridTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  GridTable = GetDT()
  FillTable(GridTable)
  DataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable
  Color_Grid()
End Sub


Function GetDT() As DataTable
  Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
  dt.Columns.Add("Days", GetType(Int16))
  dt.Columns.Add("InStock", GetType(Int16))
  dt.Columns.Add("Committed", GetType(Int16))
  dt.Columns.Add("Segment", GetType(String))
  dt.Columns.Add("Product", GetType(String))
  dt.Columns.Add("ItemName", GetType(String))
  Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillTable(dt As DataTable)
  dt.Rows.Add(10, 10, 10, "Accessories", "Adapter", "M11m22ma usb-c")
  dt.Rows.Add(18, 10, 10, "Accessories", "Adapter", "M11m22ma usb-c")
  dt.Rows.Add(25, 10, 10, "Accessories", "Adapter", "M11m22ma usb-c")
  dt.Rows.Add(30, 0, 10, "Accessories", "Adapter", "M11m22ma usb-c")
  dt.Rows.Add(35, 0, 0, "Accessories", "Adapter", "M11m22ma usb-c")
End Sub

Private Sub Color_Grid()
  For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If (Not DataGridView1.Rows(i).IsNewRow) Then
      If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Days").Value <= 15) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
      ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Days").Value >= 16) And (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Days").Value <= 21) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
      ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Days").Value > 22) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato
        If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("InStock").Value = 0) Then
          If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Committed").Value > 0) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Sorted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Sorted
  Color_Grid()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
  If (e.RowIndex >= 0) And (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
    Dim rowIndex As Int16 = e.RowIndex
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Days").Value <= 15) Then
      DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Days").Value >= 16) And (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Days").Value <= 21) Then
      DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Days").Value > 21) Then
      DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Color_Grid` to the Grid_Sorted Event.

```
Private Sub Grid_Sorted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Sorted
    Color_Grid()
End Sub
```

Comment: i have included Color_Grid() in Sorted event but it does not work.

Comment: Are you reseting or chaging the Grid Datasource or the `oModel` table in any other piece of your code?

Comment: No, i did not change the grid datasource.